# How to submit_to_remote in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

We used to have a form in our Rails 2.3.5 application as below which worked perfectly

```
<% form_for @quote do |f| -%>
    <%= f.text_field :length %>
    <%= f.text_field :tax, :readonly => true %>
    <%= submit_to_remote 'commit', 'Calculate', :url => { :action => 'create' } %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>  
<% end %>
```

Basically the 'Calculate' button would submit the form as a XMLHttpRequest request while the 'Submit' button would do a simple POST.  Is it possible to do this in a Rails 3 application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `:remote => true` to your `form_for` options to generate a form with `data-remote="true"`, which Rail's [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Unobtrusive+JavaScript) will submit via AJAX.

```
<% form_for @quote, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :length %>
    <%= f.text_field :tax, :readonly => true %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>  
<% end %>
```

The form will be submitted via AJAX if JavaScript is available, and fallback to a regular form post-back otherwise.

Comment: Our goal is to have two buttons in the same form -- one that does a XMLHttpRequest and one that does a POST similar to the Rails 2.3.5 form in the question in Rails 3.

Comment: @pckabeer No, just make *good edits*. Your edits typically just change wording while introducing spelling/grammar mistakes. Find a better way to contribute.

Comment: @meager Starting to study the system , will do in good ones , but dont downvote for that :).

Comment: @pckabeer You've been caught gaming the system at least once, and now you're doing it again by abusing the editing system. Stop abusing the system and we'll get along.

Comment: @meagar how can you tell I am abusing , this is an open wiki.I am correcting what all i can.Removing unwanted words , adding in edits.Can you please explain your view.

Comment: @pckabeer You're making trivial edits to the first few words in a post, ignoring the rest of the post and all the mistakes found there. Your edits *do* remove words, but the result is often broken English that is no better than it was.

Comment: @meagar thanks , thats the problem .So i have to correct the whole post right.I will try it next timee onwards.Now you have downvoted and brough me to a position where i cant even post my question . So sad of that.

Comment: @meagar till now my know how was that wiki gets its quality by multiple corrections.So if a person corrects a word , that also meant to the contribution.Correct me if I am wrong.